# Find the diameter of the new sphere assuming that the volume of a sphere is proportional to the cube of its diameter

Tags: spherical-geometry, solid-geometry

Find the diameter of the new sphere assuming that the volume of  a sphere is proportional to the cube of its diameter. I know that diameter is equal to the twice of radius. How can you possibly solve this if the radius in the formula of the sphere is radius cube.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "new" sphere? Anyway, if $D$ is the diameter and $R$ the radius and if you have $V=\alpha R^3$

You will have $V=\alpha (\dfrac{D}{2})^3$...